# Bind IsExpaned to my own custom TreeViewItem in Wpf?

Tags: wpf

I want to bind my custom `TreeViewItem` to `IsExpanded`.

The normal way without a custom TreeView Item would look like this.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
          <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"></Setter>
      </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But I want to bind it to my own TreeViewItem for example named `CoolTreeItemModel`.

CoolTreeItemModel could look like this:

```
  public class CoolTreeItemModel : XY
{
    public LocalTreeItemModel()
    {
        TreeViewItems = new List<CoolTreeItemModel>();
    }

    public List<CoolTreeItemModel> TreeViewItems { get; set; }
    public SomeType IsValid { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

How CoolTreeItemModel is bound:

```
 <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeRoots}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="models:CoolTreeItemModel" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewItems}"></HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate> 
 </TreeView>
```

How can I bind to the `IsExpanded` property of `CoolTreeItemModel` ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mm8 is it better now ?

Comment: @mm8 you are right now it should be clear ?

Comment: What do you mean ? why should I bind my TreeView ? I set the TreeViews Item Source with the tree root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal way" is applicable in this case. Each `CoolTreeItemModel` will be implicitly wrapped in a `TreeViewItem` container so you should be able to bind to your `IsExpanded` property. You may want to set the `Mode` of the binding to `TwoWay` though:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is it implicitly wrapped ? What do you mean.

Comment: A TreeViewItem container is created automatically by the control for each CoolTreeItemModel node in the ItemsSource.

Comment: And how can I access now the `IsExpanded` of that container or even the container itself ?

Comment: You don't access the container. You set the source property of your CoolTreeItemModel object.

Comment: This does not work because it can not find the property.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course you can "find" the property that you have defined yourself...?

Comment: Got it thank you so much. I was just stupid. The Designer just did not supported it.

Answer (score -2):

Binding requires the use of dependency properties.  [Dependency Properties On MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview)  You would need to define a dependency property like so:

```
public ClassName
{

 public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(ClassName));

 public bool IsExpanded 
 {
     get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
     set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
 }
}
```

From there you can then include the namespace of your class in the top of your xaml and then bind to `IsExpanded` like normal

```
<MyNamespace:ClassName IsExpanded="{Binding Value}" />
```

I Would like to raise one concern of my though. When developers new to XAML/WPF start developing their own controls, the distinction between view data and business data gets muddled.  If this is your own control to be consumed by others, there is an entire style template that may need to be created and used.  All of this binding should be taking place in this style template, following the example set forth by Microsoft.  Also a custom control should have no view model or defined data context as it is expected to be provided by the consumer, meaning a lot of your logic is going to be in the code behind, which is okay as a custom control is only view related and shouldn't have any business logic in it.

Comment: thanks. But that would require that `ClassName` inherits from `DependencyObject` which I can not do because in my code the `ClassName` inherits yet.

Comment: ok. I got an error that `GetValue` and `SetValue` are not existing in the current context. Thought that I have to inherit from `DependencyObject`. How can I fix this ?